# DIfferent login (sessions) for different folders

Tags: php, session

I have a webservice which requires a login from the user and i create the standard
$_SESSION['XXX'] variables for the user.

I wanted to create a "demo" of my application so i created another folder for it.
Same code in there and everything except the database.

Problem is that when the user logs in one of those two it can access both.
So if he logs in in the demo application which will set a session variable with that
same thing he'll be able to access the "normal" application.

How can i separate those two loggins?
Should i change my session variable for the demo or is there another way to solve it
according to the folder the files are in?

Thanks

Comment: What about a new session id? On your main, you check for `$_SESSION['XXX']` and on your demo you look for `$_SESSION['demo_XXX']`

Comment: EDIT: Saw your edit, yeap sounds right

Comment: I am using nginx with memcache as session handler and I pass a different prefix to all my domains (also works with different folders on the same domain) using this: `fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE memcached.sess_prefix=memc.sess.domainxy_demo.key.;`

Comment: Try something like this: `$_SESSION['current']=&$_SESSION[trim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']),'/')];` (untested). Each sub-directory will be accessed through the same variable. This does not require any change on the session path or anything else. You just set the values into `$_SESSION['current']` and you can have multiple sub-dirs with multiple sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [different paths](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-path) for the session cookie in the 2 applications.

Obviously you can't have the 2 settings in one php.ini file hence:

- set the php_admin_value in a locationMatch directive in the httpd.conf (apache)
- set the php_admin value in a .htaccess file
- add a prepend to the PHP scripts (or amend a common include file) to set the path.

Note that if you're specifying the path in code, then session_set_cookie_params() is recommnded over ini_set(). Assuming the default config in php.ini is for the demo site (which should be using something like '/demo/' NOT '/')...

```
 if (false===strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'demo') { 
     // using live application
     session_set_cookie_params (1200, '/live/');
 }
```

(the above must be run before calling session_start())

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem. And i also solved it. For example if you are taking 2 variables which are Name and ID from both site, you just change the variable name like below:

For Site1:

```
$_SESSION['username_site1'] = $username;
$_SESSION['id_site1'] = $id;
```

And for site2:

```
$_SESSION['username_site2'] = $username;
$_SESSION['id_site2'] = $id;
```

In this way two site will have two different session names and will never let you get into each other.

Let me know if it worked for you also.

regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the path to which the session data is saved...

N.B. Ensure the folder exists and is writable by the webserver user (e.g. nobody)

`<?php
  $newPath = '/tmp/sessions/demo';
  ini_set('session.save_path',$newPath);
?>`